# Move/resize window on any part by modifier+touchpad (not clicking, just tapping)

Tags: touchpad, window-manager

Does any window manager have the capability of moving/resizing a window by using <kbd>Modifier</kbd> + Touchpad, by tapping (not clicking) at any part of the window?

I know, that a most window managers are capable of moving a window by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Left clicking, and resizing by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Right click. This works perfectly with a mouse. But, with a touchpad, it is more convoluted, at it needs to hold down two buttons: <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a button for click.

Ideally, I'd like to move a window by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Touchpad, and resize by <kbd>Super</kbd> + Touchpad. I mean, I'd hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and with just tapping and moving my finger, I'd like to move a window. Can any window manager do this? If not, is there any hack to accomplish this?

Currently I'm using xfce4 with `xfwm`. It would be the best, if I could do this with just replacing `xfwm` with another `wm`, or with using some external utility on top of `xfwm`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that fusuma and following  plugins are helpful.

https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma-plugin-wmctrl
https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma-plugin-keypress

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little program, which injects mouse click events into the X server, when Alt/Win button pressed and there's a touch. The path of the event devices should be changed to point to the keyboard and touchpad respectively (it works for me for `event0` and `event5`, but on another machines they are likely to be different). The window manager should be configured that Alt+LeftClick is move and Win+RightClick is resize. Here is the source code:

```
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main() {
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);

    int kfd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY);
    int tfd = open("/dev/input/event5", O_RDONLY);
    int mfd = kfd;
    if (tfd>mfd) mfd = tfd;
    bool leftAltDown = false;
    bool leftWinDown = false;
    bool touch = false;
    bool leftClickStateOnServer = false;
    bool rightClickStateOnServer = false;
    for (;;) {
        fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(kfd, &readfds);
        FD_SET(tfd, &readfds);
        int e = select(mfd+1, &readfds, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (e>=0) {
            if (FD_ISSET(kfd, &readfds)) {
                input_event e;
                if (read(kfd, &e, sizeof(e))==sizeof(e)) {
                    if (e.type==EV_KEY) {
                        if (e.code==56) leftAltDown = e.value;
                        if (e.code==125) leftWinDown = e.value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(tfd, &readfds)) {
                input_event e;
                read(tfd, &e, sizeof(e));
                if (e.type==EV_KEY&&e.code==BTN_TOUCH) {
                    touch = e.value;
                }
            }
        }

        bool leftClick = leftAltDown&&touch;
        bool rightClick = leftWinDown&&touch;

        if (leftClickStateOnServer!=leftClick) {
            leftClickStateOnServer = leftClick;
            XTestFakeButtonEvent(display, Button1, leftClick, CurrentTime);
            XSync(display, false);
        }
        if (rightClickStateOnServer!=rightClick) {
            rightClickStateOnServer = rightClick;
            XTestFakeButtonEvent(display, Button3, rightClick, CurrentTime);
            XSync(display, false);
        }
    }
}
```